# ActivityManager kills running process of system app

Tags: android, process

We are currently facing the problem that the ActivityManager kills our system app:

**"I/ActivityManager(  831): Killing 3267:de.oursystemapp.tsc/u0a199 (adj 15): empty #31"**

Why could this happen? We don't have any UI parts for this system app, it just lives in the background. After boot of the device IntentServices are triggered by the app to download data from the backend.  I don't understand why my process could be considered as empty?

I don't really have an explanation right now, so any ideas would help.

Comment: Is your app process actually doing anything at the time that Android should be aware of as useful work?  What is going on in the foreground when this happens?  Are other things being killed as well?

Comment: This is been already answered, please read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645193/foreground-service-being-killed-by-android

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? I have the similar problem with my tv box. Thanks.