# Foreground Service being killed on Notification click

Tags: android, service, android-notifications, foreground-service

In Android 4.4.2 clicking on my Foreground Service notification is killing my process.

On older devices (Samsuing Tab 2 running 4.2.2), I can swipe away the Activity from Recent Tasks and still have my `Service` running fine in the background. Then when I click on the `Notification` my app `Activity` starts again quite happily.

However, once I click the Notification on my Nexus 7 running 4.4.2 my process is killed (which up until the click is running happily in the background). The `PendingIntent` doesn't seem to fire at all, or at least, it doesn't hit the first line of the `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
05-21 16:17:38.939: I/ActivityManager(522): Killing 2268:com.test.student/u0a242 (adj 0): remove task
```

I've run through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14293528/726954) answer, and using the command `dumpsys activity proccesses` I've confirmed that my Service *is* running in the foreground correctly.

So, what is it about clicking this Notification which is killing my process?

Code involved in moving the Service to the Foreground follows:

Service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("NativeWrappingService", "Starting Service...");
    startForeground(NotificationIcon.NOTIFICATION_STUDENT, NotificationManager.getStudentIcon(this).getNotification());    
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

NotificationIcon: (`getStudentIcon(this).getNotification()`)

```
public Notification getNotification() {
    Builder mBuilder = new Builder(mContext);

    if(mSmallIcon   != -1)      mBuilder.setSmallIcon(mSmallIcon);
    if(mLargeIcon   != null)    mBuilder.setLargeIcon(mLargeIcon);
    if(mTitle       != null)    mBuilder.setContentTitle(mTitle);
    if(mSubTitle    != null)    mBuilder.setContentText(mSubTitle);
    if(mSubTitleExtra != null)  mBuilder.setContentInfo(mSubTitleExtra);

    mBuilder.setOngoing(mOngoing);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(mAutoCancel);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(getPendingIntent(mContext, mAction, mBundle, mActivity));

    return mBuilder.build();
}

private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context context, String action, Bundle extras, String activity) {
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, BroadcastToOrderedBroadcast.class);
    Bundle bundle;
    if(extras != null)  bundle = extras;
    else                bundle = new Bundle();

    if(activity != null && !activity.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        BundleUtils.addActivityToBundle(bundle, activity);
    }

    BundleUtils.addActionToBundle(bundle, action);

    newIntent.putExtras(bundle);

    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(NativeService.getInstance(), mNotificationID, newIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Comment: It is a known bug which is being tracked [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53313). Can you try the solution listed in [comment #7](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53313#c7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add [FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND) flag to the PendingIntent used from your notification in order to allow the Service to run at Foreground priority.

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, BroadcastToOrderedBroadcast.class);
newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(NativeService.getInstance(), mNotificationID, newIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Here is the source of this information : [Android Issue Tracker tool](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53313#c7).

Comment: Isn't it equivalent to FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK? They both are 0x10000000, can you support the reference that I can set FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND at all?

Comment: @Manish Mulimani i went through your suggestion.
When my app is closed and if i click the notification my service is getting restarted . And the BroadCast receiver is also not working?