# How to kill foreground service of third party android application

Tags: java, android, android-service, foreground-service

Android system allows us to kill background processes of other installed android applications using below permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

and

```
void killBackgroundProcesses (String packageName) API
```

But is there any way to kill **foreground service** of third party applications?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreground service being killed by Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645193/foreground-service-being-killed-by-android)

Comment: @SerjArdovic From what I can make out, that doesn't look like a duplicate: the one you quote is all about _not being killed_ (by Android's clean-up code). As far as I can see, the OP wants to explicitly kill someone else's process.