# foreground service getting killed when app is swiped off

Tags: android, service

I hope title itself says what's my question is.

I have a `Service` which runs in foreground.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, WidgetFlashReceiver.class)
                    .setAction(Constants.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICK),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setOngoing(true);
    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.setContentTitle("Sample Service");
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE;
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

but this Service getting killed when app is swiped off from recent tasks even though it is a foreground Service.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645193/foreground-service-being-killed-by-android

Comment: what you want exactly ?

Comment: @Vaishali I dont want my service to be killed when my app is swiped off from recent tasks.

Comment: See the answer if it helps to you then give it up :P

Comment: Is that the only service in your app? Are there any activities or services currently bound to one of your services with the `Intent.BIND_AUTO_CREATE` flag at the time you swipe away the app?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this [comment](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53313#c7) about the Android bug, I found this solution that solve the problem for me!

```
AlarmManager almgr = (AlarmManager)MyContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent timerIntent = new Intent(MyUniqueLabel);
timerIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
PendingIntent pendingOffLoadIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyContext, 1, timerIntent, 0);
```

> you MUST do these things for it to work.
>
> 1.) Call addFlags and the intent and pass it in FLAG_RECEIVER_FORGROUND
>
> 2.) Use a non-zero request code in PendingIntent.getBroadcast
>
> If you leave any of those steps out it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in android that describes the same issue you're facing: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53313

Also, there's a lot of info on the matter in SO:

[Foreground service being killed by Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645193/foreground-service-being-killed-by-android)

[Service being killed while holding wake lock and after calling startForeground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317696/service-being-killed-while-holding-wake-lock-and-after-calling-startforeground)

Answer (score 0):

Check your service to see if you have overriden the onTaskRemoved() method. Make sure you are not calling stopSelf() method there.

Answer (score -2):

add below code in your manifest file

```
     <service
        android:name="com.example.service.NameOfYourService"
        android:process=":remote" >
    </service>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer friend... but I already tried this. Still getting killed

Comment: can u alble to put ur code in to 
@Override
 public void onStart(Intent intent, int id) method ?

Answer (score -2):

use the service [onTaskRemoved()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent)) method.